# C++ user enters floating point instead of integer

Tags: c++, input

Im trying to get the program to only accept x as an integer then ask for another integer, y. However when i enter a floating point into x it takes the decimal part of the input and makes that the y value. i am unsure of my mistake here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int getInt()
{
    int x = 0;
    while (!(cin >> x))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Please input a proper 'whole' number: " << endl;
    }
    return (x);
}

int toobig()
{
    cout << "Your number is too large, please enter something smaller: " << endl;
    int x = getInt();
    return (x);
}

int toosmall()
{
    cout << "your number is negative, please enter a positive number: " << endl;
    int x = getInt();
    return (x);
}


int main()
{

    cout << "your number please:-" << endl;
    int x = getInt();

    if (x>100000)
    {
        toobig();
    }
    else if (x<0)
    {
        toosmall();
    }

    int y = 0;

    cout << "enter y " << endl;
    cin >> y;

    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "Y" value? If you enter "123.456" and read it as an integer, the 123 are going to be read as the integer.

Comment: Maybe you can check if the user enters `'.'` after the first integer, and return an error in that case?

Comment: yes x would be 123 however after this is entered the program immediately prints X = 123 Y = 0.

Comment: Why don't you just read a line, then check if all characters are within the `0-9` range? I think your design has a problem that it is too complicated and can't handle an easy problem.

Comment: Add an example of imput/output. It is difficult to understand where the problem is. If you enter a floating point x is read and the sentence to read y fails

Comment: do you mean to check that each individual character is between 0 and 9 so that an error occurs when the program find the "." ?

Comment: By the way, `toobig` and `toosmall` both return the input but you are not capturing it in your main.

Comment: This does not make any sense. Once the program reads `"123"`, it will get stuck on the `"."` and return false for the second input. You're explicitly testing for that in `getInt` and showing an error message, so you should be seeing that error. Are you not?

Answer (score 1):

Most conversions to `int` stop as soon as they find something that can't be part of an `int` and only a few conversion functions tell you if they stop before parsing the whole string.

Let's use [one of those few](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), shall we?

```
int getInt()
{
    for ( ; ; ) // loop until user provides something we can use. 
                // This is dangerous. You probably want to give up after a while.
    {
        std::string input; // read in as string
        if (std::cin >> input)
        {
            char * endp; // will be updated with pointer to where conversion stopped
            errno = 0;

            // convert string to int
            long rval  = std::strtol (input.c_str(), &endp, 10); 
            if (*endp == '\0') // check whole string was read
            {
                if (errno != ERANGE) // check converted number did not overflow long
                {
                    if (rval >= std::numeric_limits<int>::min() &&
                        rval <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                         // check converted number did not overflow int
                         // you could replace this min and max with your own passed-in 
                         // min and max values if you want
                    {
                        return rval; // return the known-to-be-good int
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        { // note: usually when cin fails to read a string, it's over. 
          // This is actually a good time to throw an exception because this 
          // just shouldn't happen.
            std::cin.clear(); // but for now we'll just clear the error and 
                              // probably enter an infinite loop of failure
        }
        // failed for any reason. Blow off all user input and re-prompt
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Please input a proper 'whole' number: " << std::endl;
    }
    return 0; // to satisfy compiler because a non-void function must always return. 
              // Never reached because of infinite for loop.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since every console input on C++ is treated as a string, then under your getInt() method I would do the following:

```
       int GetInt(istream &stream)
       {
        char obtainChar; //read a character from input   
        int x;    

        stream >> x;  

        while(stream.fail() || (stream.peek() != '\r' && stream.peek() != '\n'))
        {
            stream.clear(); //clear the fail state of stream
            obtainChar = stream.get(); //read a character from input

            while(obtainChar != '\n' && obtainChar != EOF) //while gotten char is not a return key or EOF
                obtainChar = stream.get(); //read a character from input iterate up to '\n' or EOF
            //displays an error message if there was a bad input (e.g. decimal value)
            cerr << endl << "Please input a proper 'whole' number: " << endl;
            cout << endl << "Please re-enter x: "; //re-prompt to re-enter a value

             x = GetInt(stream); //Try again by calling the function again (recursion)
        }
            return x; //will return after the user enters ONLY if an integer was inputted
    }
```

the first while is basically saying, if the stream (console input) does fails or the next stream char (.peek()) is not a \r or a \n  the clear the stream and get the first character.

while that char is not a \n and not End Of File (EOF) then obtain the next char, so on and so forth.

if a problem occurred then display a error message to the user and re-prompt the user for the value of x.

then call the same function to re-test the input (recursively), if all is well then return the value of x.

you can now call this function to evaluate the value of Y.

NOTE: istream is part of the iostream library is basically cin

NOTE: call the function like so:

```
int x;
cout << "your number please:-" << endl;
x = GetInt(cin);
```